# Hide #DIV/0! errors and #N/A errors

Tags: google-sheets

I want to hide all #DIV/0! errors and #N/A errors for data that hasn't been inputted. (So just have an empty cell.) The current data I have:

[image: Data sample]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Rather than using the `IF` formula, I suggest using the `IFERROR` formula. That way you won't need to worry about possible error conditions.

Case of `#VALUE!` error:

```
=IFERROR("a" + 1,"")
```

Case of `#DIV/0!` error:

```
=IFERROR(3/0,"")
```

The second parameter is optional, so you can even simplify the formulas to:

```
=IFERROR("a" + 1)
=IFERROR(3/0)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using an if() statement, testing to see if there is an entry in the symbol column: if yes then do calculation: if not then blank.
I don't use google spreadsheets, but something like:
    =if(a1="","",calculation)
assumes column a has the symbol info.
Same goes for the divide by zero error but check that the number of shares is greater than 0:
    =if(A20>0,calculation,"")

Answer (score 0):

Set the defaut color as with (so your text/value will be invisible) and add a condition if value different of zero than set color as black. So you will see only cell with corect values